# "Event loop is closed" error in aiomysql

Tags: python, mysql, python-asyncio, peewee

I have a problem with querying MySQL using peewee-async (which in turn uses aiomysql)

Here is my code (I think it's almost identical to examples from peewee-async doc):

```
import asyncio
import peewee
import peewee_async

database = peewee_async.MySQLDatabase(None)


class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
    id = peewee.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        database = database


class User(BaseModel):
    name = peewee.CharField(unique=True)
    password = peewee.CharField()
    role = peewee.CharField()


def get_db(config, loop=None):
    database.init(config['database'], user=config['user'], password=config['password'],
                  host=config['host'], port=config['port'])
    objects = peewee_async.Manager(database, loop=loop)
    objects.allow_sync = False
    return objects


async def print_users(db):
    users = await db.execute(User.select())
    for user in users:
        print(user.id, user.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = {
        'database': 'db',
        'user': 'user',
        'password': 'secret',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 3306
    }

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    db = get_db(conf, loop=loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(print_users(db))
```

Now, when I'm executing it, it does query and prints users (1 user in my case). But then, it throws exception:

```
(env)user@Private-006:~/project$ python tst.py
1 test
Exception ignored in: <bound method Connection.__del__ of <aiomysql.connection.Connection object at 0x7f37ce016978>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/project/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 802, in __del__
  File "/home/user/project/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aiomysql/connection.py", line 269, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 566, in close
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 497, in call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 506, in _call_soon
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 334, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It seems that adding `loop.run_until_complete(db.close())` in the end helps.
Let's consider this as answer for now, until somebody explains why we should explicitly close manager, and why this is not mentioned in peewee-async documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. There are two solutions works for me,  the code is as follows:

first, call method close_async of database:

```
await database.close_async()
```

second,

```
await objects.close()
```

Read the source code, you will find objects.close() call database.close_async().